# Search text file and return values after equal sign

Tags: c++

I am reading in a file and want to return certain values after the equal sign

The text file looks like this

```
slicenum=1
imageWidth=100
ID=1
```

etc. and then repeats for each slice of the image

For now, I am focusing on ID, but eventually I want to have an array I guess of all the values I want to extract.

When I do this, it just prints the whole file. How do I print just the value after the equals sign of the ID?

```
string ID;
string line;
while (getline(inFile, line)) {
        if (line.find(ID) != string::npos)
            cout << line << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: You are trying to find a substring held by variable ID (which is empty string) in a string held by line variable. If the returned iterator is not npos you print the whole line. You need to search the line for '=' and use that iterator as an end marker for substring call on the line if you want to get whats in front of =.

Answer (score 0):

Use `std::string::substr` and `std::string::find`

```
const size_t pos = line.find('=');
if (pos != std::string::npos) {
    std::cout << line.substr(pos + 1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this will help you:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>
#include<string>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    ifstream in("Text.txt");
    string beforeEqual = "";
    string afterEqual = "";
    while (!in.eof())
    {
        getline(in, beforeEqual, '='); //grtting string upto =
        getline(in, afterEqual, '\n'); //getting string after =
        cout << afterEqual << endl; //printing string agter =
    }
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```